# socket.io emit to everyone except for some certain clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

In my Node.js server, I have an array of client IDs, and I have a socket that I want to send to all connected clients except for the clients I have in that array, so I want to emit to all clients excluding some clients that i have defined by id, is that possible?

Comment: yes, it's possible but you have to share some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering my own question after some research.**

One thing you could do is to add the clients you want to exclude inside of a [Scoket.io room](https://socket.io/docs/v4/rooms/index.html) and then emit to everyone except for that room, like shown below:

```
io.except("room1").emit(/* ... */); // to all clients except the ones in "room1"
```

Note that this feature was implemented in version `socket.io@4.0.0.`
here is [documentation for it](https://socket.io/docs/v3/migrating-from-3-x-to-4-0/#Allow-excluding-specific-rooms-when-broadcasting)